# How to bypass basic authentication pop-up using Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, webautomation, automation-testing

I am currently facing a challenge while attempting to automate the handling of an alert generated by a specific link using Selenium WebDriver. Upon clicking the link, an alert pops up, but my WebDriver is encountering difficulties in switching to this alert.
I have attempted to diagnose the issue by capturing the page source and taking a screenshot for analysis using the following code snippets:

enter image description here[enter image description here][1]

This is what the site look like[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKlO5.png)

Code:

```py
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("   ")
time.sleep(3)
print(driver.page_source)
driver.save_screenshot("screenshot.png")
alert = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.alert_is_present())
alert.send_keys("  ")
alert.send_keys(Keys.TAB)  # Move to the password field
alert.send_keys("  ")
alert.accept()`
```

the WebDriver is reporting an error stating, "No Alert Found," signifying its inability to switch to the alert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is generic Authentication popup. To bypass it, you can pass your credentials inside url

```py
def authenticate(driver, login, password, url):
    driver.get(f"https://{login}:{password}@{url}")

authenticate(driver, 'admin','admin','the-internet.herokuapp.com/basic_auth')
```